# CoreData fetch entities with same values

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a CoreData entity called Item with two values (well, two values relevant to this question).

```
Item
---------------
id - NSString
name - NSString
```

Every item has a unique ID and SHOULD have a unique name.

(BTW, the id is not used for CoreData it is used for communicating with the server).

There are a couple of items which appear to have duplicate names and I'm trying to find a query that returns all items that have an item in the table with a duplicate name.

Is this possible?

If so, can someone provide an NSPredicate (or method) to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that it is possible to fetch exactly the items with duplicate names with a Core Data fetch request. (I think there was a similar question some time ago here on SO, but I cannot find it right now.)

You could fetch all items sorted by the `name` attribute. Then the duplicates can be found with a single loop over the result array.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at doing it the way you suggested.

Comment: Well, this is odd. I did this and I don't have any dupes but for some reason my NSFC is showing each entity twice in the TableView.